# Why does single-user with heredocs and multiline queries throw syntax errors for postgres+docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

So I'm trying to create a Postgres database running on Docker. I have the following file `/Users/wwerner/programming/test/dockerdb/build_db.sh`:

```
echo "************* Here comes your db! ****************"
gosu postgres postgres --single <<- EOSQL
    CREATE SCHEMA test;

    CREATE TABLE test.will_fail (
        id integer NOT NULL,
        name character varying NOT NULL);
EOSQL
echo ""
echo "************* You just got your db! ****************"
```

When I run the following:

```
docker run --name testy -v /Users/wwerner/programming/test/dockerdb/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pw -d -p 5432 postgres:9.4
```

I get the following logs:

```
backend> 
************* Here comes your db! ****************

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.3
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input at character 35
STATEMENT:      CREATE TABLE test.will_fail (

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id" at character 9
STATEMENT:          id integer NOT NULL,

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "name" at character 9
STATEMENT:          name character varying NOT NULL);

backend> backend> backend> backend> backend> backend> 
************* You just got your db! ****************
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-06-12 16:05:38 UTC
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

However, if I make the `CREATE TABLE` statement be one line, it will work just fine.

Why is that, and how can I use multiline statements?

EDIT: 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246926/344286) looks like it will solve my problem, but my question **why** still remains.

Comment: @MarcB nope, it's definitely the newlines that are getting it.

Comment: FWIW, the question you linked to has this `gosu postgres postgres --single **-jE** <<- EOSQL`.  Have you looked up what they do?

Comment: Didn't catch the `-jE` part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `postgres` binary to submit SQL commands (as opposed to `psql`), the end-of-line is the end of the command and the semi-colon has no meaning.

Per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html):

> Normally, the single-user mode server treats newline as the command
>   entry terminator; there is no intelligence about semicolons, as there
>   is in psql. To continue a command across multiple lines, **you must type
>   backslash just before each newline except the last one**.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `-j` flag. From the [man](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html) page:

> ```
>  -j
>        Disables use of newline as a statement delimiter.
> ```