# postgresql: can't get docker postgres container in single user mode

Tags: postgresql, docker

I need to start my postgresql server in single user mode so I can restore the superuser role.
IN this case it is the standard docker image for postgres10

I bash into the container.
as user postgres and from /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin I do:

```
./pg_ctl stop -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

as a first step before starting it in single mode.

I see
waiting for server to shut down ...

and then I am dumped back to the host.

I have worked out it is nothing to do with the restart policy.

EDIT: the postgresql server process is pid 1 so the container exits when postgresql stops.

Comment: Complicated. You probably have to install PostgreSQL outside the container and start the server on the data directory (of course after stopping the container).

Comment: I will first try putting a script in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/q/28244869/401226

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you need to start the container like with a shell and without the postgresql server process starting as pid=1, which is how the container normally works. It seems like you are trapped: you can't stop the postgresql server without killing the container.

You need the database volume because roles are stored with the database. So you also need to discover how the database volume is mounted to your container (it may be obvious if you have a named volume, but I use ansible for deployment, so I don't have a named volume.)

So with the docker container running normally (my container when running normally is named `django_api_sync_db` and the postgres image is `postgres:10`
The owner user which lost superuser role due to bad ansible copy and paste is `django_api_sync_db`)

`docker inspect django_api_sync_db`

and search for the Mounts section.
In my case, I see a bind mount:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/docker/django_api_sync/db",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

stop the container, and then restart it with an interactive shell like this (in my case with postgresql v 10):

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source="/var/docker/django_api_sync/db",target="/var/lib/postgresql/data"  -it postgres:10 /bin/bash
```

now, postgresql is not running. If curious, do

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps`

and

`ps -ef`

(aside: The default entry point of the postgres image means the postgresql server is pid 1, so you can't go into single user mode without immediately terminating the container.)

Since we are now in the container, discover the directory with the binaries.
Note: we are root.

`# which postgres`

my output is: `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres`

Change user and go into postgres single user mode:

```
su postgres

/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

and from the backend:

`backend> alter user django_api_sync with superuser;`

You are finished. Exit and do whatever you need to do to get the database container running normally again (e.g. `systemctl restart docker`)

Comment: Are you launching this originally from Compose? [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) will use the `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml`, so you don't have to rediscover them.

Comment: My deployment uses an ansible playbook which uses just docker and has this line
  `volumes: /var/docker/django_api_sync/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/`

I don't know much about docker. On my dev machine I use docker compose. I was very, very confused about how to mount the volume in production until I did the docker inspect and saw it was a "bind" mount. Hence, documented for posterity.